# Xamarin Android with MVVMLight: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvm-light

I'm getting this error everytime I update a ViewModel property already binded in the activity. I know this error is related with update UI from another thread (not UI thread) but I can not control how MVVMLight do the binding...

The activity:

```
private readonly List<Binding> _bindings = new List<Binding>();

public PersonViewModel ViewModel
{
    get
    {
        return App.Locator.Detail;
    }
}

private TextView _txtName;
public TextView TxtName
{
    get
    {
        return _txtName ??
            (_txtName = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtName));
    }
}

protected async override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Detail);

    _bindings.Add(this.SetBinding(
        () => ViewModel.Person.Name,
        () => TxtName.Text));

    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { ViewModel.LoadDetailCommand.Execute(null); });
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
private IDataService _dataService;

private PersonObj _person; 
public PersonObj Person
{
    get
    {
        return _person;
    }
    set
    {
        Set(ref _person, value);
    }
}

private RelayCommand _loadDetailCommand;
public RelayCommand LoadDetailCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _loadDetailCommand
               ?? (_loadDetailCommand = new RelayCommand(
                   async () =>
                   {
                       await LoadDataAsync();
                   }));
    }
}

public PersonViewModel(IDataService dataService)
{
    _dataService = dataService;
}

private async Task LoadDataAsync()
{
    try
    {
        Person= await _dataService.GetPerson(0);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Exception here!!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I managed it creating the task when necesary in the ViewModel and awaiting it so I can catch all posible exceptions:

```
Person = await Task.Run(async () =>
{
    var p = await _dataService.GetPerson(0);
    return p;
});
```

Thanks @xleon for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about MVVMLight, but I´d try to change this line:

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { ViewModel.LoadDetailCommand.Execute(null); });
```

for this one:

```
ViewModel.LoadDetailCommand.Execute(null);
```

You shouldn´t need to start a new task to execute commands

And this one:

```
protected async override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

for this one:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

Comment: I know I shouldn't, but LoadDetailCommand (_dataService.GetPerson) executes a Network call with httpclient and gives me an "NetworkOnMainThreadException" exception... If I encapsulate it in a Task.Run how can I catch the errors?

Comment: Any task inside `async void` method will not produce exceptions even if you use `try/catch`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: The method is not void: "private async Task LoadDataAsync()"

Comment: This line `protected async override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` was on your question.